# Should I link to images when sending a html Email or use `AddEmbeddedImage`?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've seen that when using `addEmbeddedImage()` Images appear as attachments in the email, which seems kind of weird if I want to send a confirmation email for an account, or a password change and stuff like that. When I checked other emails from other websites they just use links as the source of the image.

Is this the best practice? If so, should I host the images that I'm using in emails in a special way, or anywhere among the other website files is fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded images are also attachments. What makes them different is that they have `cid` values, so HTML in the same message can reference them. Whether images are displayed inline *as well as* displayed as attachments is dependent on the mail client, so you'd need to test it for your particular application.

Pros of embedding/attaching:

- Does not require a connection to display images
- For that reason, is often permitted by default, not blocked by filters
- Images remain working even if the original site goes offline

Cons of embedding/attaching:

- Messages are bigger and slower to send, consume unnecessary bandwidth regardless of whether the recipient reads the message
- Unfriendly to mobile as it prevents them exercising control over the image display

Pros of linking:

- Messages are much smaller & faster to send
- Images are not downloaded until the message is viewed, making traffic much less "peaky"
- Images can be revised after sending (e.g. rendered dynamically when a message is read)
- Images do not appear as attachments
- Images are not used at all by recipients who prefer plain text (e.g. those with visual impairments)

Cons of linking:

- Image display is blocked by default in most email clients

If you're just doing a one-time send of a couple of images (e.g. family), embedding/attaching is appropriate, but if you're sending high volumes, linked images are usually preferable. If you're thinking of putting images in your email signatures, don't - it's possible to make good-looking email layouts without using images. Also be aware that Outlook's image handling is particularly bad.

How you choose to serve the images is irrelevant - the client can't tell whether you're serving static images from files or rendering something dynamically, so just serve them like you would for a web site.